# if $f$ is of prime order, then can the orbit of $s$ under $f$ have one element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> *if $f\in A(S)$* has order $p$, $p$ a prime, show that for every $s\in S$ the orbit of $s$ under $f$ has one or $p$ elements.*

Since the cyclic group generated by $f$ has $p$ elements, therefore $p$ elements for $s$'s orbit. But can you show me when $s$'s orbit only contains one element please?

Comment: You should get used to define your non-standard notation: is $\;A(S)\;$ the alternating symmetric subgroup of some set $\;S\;$?

Comment: @DonAntonio yes, it is

Comment: Thanks, @pxc3110 . It is either denoted more commonly by $\;A_n\;$ , if $\;S=\{1,2,...,n\}\;$ , or for a general set $\;S\;$ as $\;Alt(S)\;$ ....or by whatever thing the author of some given paper/book decides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily prove this by looking at the action of $\;H:=\langle f\rangle\;$, instead of **all** $\;A(S)\;$,  on $\;S\;$ , and then:

$$\forall\,s\in S\;,\;\;\;|\mathcal Orb_H(s)|=[H:H_s]$$

But what are the possible indexes of subgroups of $\;H\;$ ...?

Comment: I think the question (although it may have been slightly unclear) was asking for examples when the orbit of $s$ under $f$ has exactly one element. I think the OP already understood that if $f$ has prime order $p$, then the size of the orbit of $s$ under $f$ is either $1$ or $p$. However, I may have misinterpreted the OP's question myself, and this is definitely useful and should clarify the OP's thinking so +1

Comment: I think you're right, @AmiteshDatta, and then the other answer addresses this. I can't understand why to ask something *in blue* and then **add** other question afterwards...!

Comment: Sorry sir, I can't read this, I'm unfamiliar with the notation

Comment: You're the one who asked about *orbits*, @pxc3110 , so I assumed you already studied actions of groups on sets, the orbit-stabilizer theorem and etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio ok...

Comment: Dear @DonAntonio, me neither. The question is indeed confusing. In any case, it seems nowadays figuring out the actual question is part of the job thrust upon people answering questions on stackexchange. Reminds me of the intricate word problems I encountered at high school, at which I admittedly was never very good ... But I'd like to think I'm better at the ones inadvertently presented to me on this website :)

Comment: @AmiteshDatta, welcome to the "I-really-loathe-university/college-level's-questions-ill-or-confusingly-posed Club". I've always said to my students, and also to some high school advanced ones: "whatever I can't understand in your exams/papers/exercises/etc I'll swiftly and automatically mark as wrong...just because of the doubt". An exemption is made to students who **really** have some writing/understanding problem, like dyslexia or stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Let $f\in A_5$ be the product of transpositions $f=(1,2)(3,4)$.

Let $s=5$.

The orbit of $s$ under $f$ contains $1$ element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help! So if the order of f is coprime to |S|, then such element will exist, I think? But can you show me please?

Comment: This is a good example. +1

Comment: Dear @pxc3110, the orbits of $f$ partition $S$, and each orbit has size either $1$ or $p$ by either your reasoning or Don Antonio's answer above. If there is no orbit of size $1$, then this implies that the order of $f$ divides $\left|S\right|$. Therefore, if the order of $f$ does not divide $\left|S\right|$, then there exists an element with orbit of size $1$.